# Rails 3: validate that a record belongs to user

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a HABTM relationship between Products and Categories. Those Categories belongs to a user.

At my product form, I only show checkboxes for the current user. But i want to validate this on model too, so users can't fake POST variables and assign it to invalid categories.

How can i do such validation?

Example: given a category_id 5, i have to check if this category belongs to current_user.id ( provided by devise ).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can add `attr_accessor: creator_id` to your `Post` model. (`creator_id` is not in database )

And send `current_user.id` from form to `Post`'s `creator_id`.

Then use model callbacks. For example `after_validation`:

```
after_validation do
  if User.find(creator_id).categories.pluck(:id).include?(category_id)
    true
  else
    errors.add :category, "is invalid for user"
  end
end
```